# Do i need to start an https server on my native app to complete a call to AcquireToken?

Tags: .net, authentication, azure-active-directory

I’m calling the following from a Native app (C# console app). To complete this (to get the token), do I need to actually start listening to a redirect call on the local machine? In https? Thanks

AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net", , new Uri("https://localhost"), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always)).Result;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't. Redirect URi is not actually loaded. It is used to indicate end of the flow and it is intercepted before being loaded in the browser control

Comment: In case of an error, the browser window does not close itself. As a result within the C# i will never get the error code/msg returned by Azure AD. If I close the window myself, I will always get the "user cancelled" exception in C#

Comment: That is by design. Adal does not parse html in the webview.

Comment: I also need to clear up cookies prior to calling AcquireTokenAsync. How can i do that? thanks

Comment: There was a parameter that did that: PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always)

Comment: It does not clear cookies. It simply tells sts to reauthenticate the user.

Comment: If the answer worked for you then can you accept it?